# Why won't Incense stop?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I used an Incense two days ago and ended up signing out during the Incense. When I signed back in the time remaining on the incense was 59:59 and started counting down. I had the purple smoke around me. I have not had time to check to see if it is actually working but it doesn't seem to be.

When the timer reaches 00:00 it goes back to 59:59 and recommences instantly. I have tried removing all incenses in my inventory (3) but that didn't work. I have signed out and back in again, still nothing. I am using a Samsung Galaxy. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Fix?! How do you *reproduce* this?

Comment: Is it only the particle effect? Or are pokemon being spawned from the incense? (Pokemon with a similar particle effect)

Comment: It sounds like the opposite of a problem, to be honest...

Comment: It should be an issue with the time on your phone. You will not be getting pokemons spawning around you since that data is populated by Niantic's servers, and they will be using the server side time. You can confirm whether the incense is actually working by checking whether the pokemons popping up has purple smokes around them.

Comment: Can you use a new incense?

Comment: Adding a photo(s) would help us to get a better idea of your problem.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest opening a support ticket. Niantic will probably hop on this right away as it's giving you an unfair advantage compared to other players.

Short of that, try uninstalling, running [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en), reinstalling, running SD Maid again, and then see if that fixes it.